# Not entering inside forloop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a number association map for phone-dialpad that looks like :

```
private Integer[][] dialpad = { {1   , 2   , 3},
                                {4   , 5   , 6},
                                {7   , 8   , 9},
                                {null, 0   , null} };
```

**Now, according to the rule association for :**

```
1 should 2,4,5
2 should be 1,3,4,5,6
3 should be 2,5,6
and so on............
```

**I have written the code to handle this in the way:**

```
public void createDialAssociation()
{
    int nosCols = dialpad[0].length;
    int nosRows = dialpad.length;
    //int rowFrom, rowTo, colFrom, colTo;

    for(int row=0; row<nosRows; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<nosCols; col++)
        {
            Integer currentElement = dialpad[row][col];
            elementAssociation.put( currentElement, new ArrayList<Integer>());

            int rowFrom =  (row-1)< 0 ? 0 : (row-1);
            int rowTo = (row+1) <= (nosRows-1)? row+1: nosRows-1;
            int colFrom = (col-1)<0 ? 0 : (col-1);
            int colTo = (col+1) <= (nosCols-1) ? col+1 : nosCols-1;

            LOG.info("row,col,element = " + row + "," +col+ ","+ currentElement);
            LOG.info("rowFrom = " + rowFrom);
            LOG.info("rowTo = " + rowTo);
            LOG.info("colFrom = " + colFrom);
            LOG.info("colTo = " + colTo);
            LOG.info("---------------------------------------------------- " );
            for(int currentRowIndex=rowFrom; currentRowIndex==rowTo; currentRowIndex++)
            {
                LOG.info("1..............");
                for(int currentColIndex = colFrom; currentColIndex == colTo ; currentColIndex++)
                {
                    LOG.info("2..............");
                    if ( currentRowIndex == row || currentColIndex == col )
                        continue;

                    if( dialpad[currentRowIndex][currentColIndex] != null)
                    {
                        elementAssociation.get(currentElement).add(dialpad[currentRowIndex][currentColIndex]);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**My problem is , the code is not going inside the loops :**

```
for(int currentRowIndex=rowFrom; currentRowIndex==rowTo; currentRowIndex++)
```

**Hence, I am not seeing the**

```
LOG.info("1.......);
or LOG.info("2........);
```

Any insight/help may I expect?

Comment: Do you mean `2 should be 1,3,4,5,6` and not `2 should be 1,3,4,5,5`?

Comment: Those `==`s in the `for`s should be `<`s. (In `for(...;currentRowIndex==rowTo;...)` and also in `for(...;currentColIndex == colTo;...)`). Perhaps `<=`s (as these `xyTo`-s seem to max at `length-1`)

Comment: Your nesting level for `for` loops is 4. If the arrays become larger, I would worry about the performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int currentRowIndex=rowFrom; currentRowIndex==rowTo; currentRowIndex++){}
```

initializes `currentRowIndex` as the value of `rowFrom`.
While `currentRowIndex==rowTo` it runs the content of the loop and after each execution of the loop runs `currentRowIndex++`.
Thus the loop is entered at most once exactly when `rowFrom==rowTo`.

You probably want to continue the loop until `currentRowIndex==rowTo`, maybe even including that case. This would mean you have to run the continue the loop while `rowFrom` is still lower than `rowTo`, so you have to write `rowFrom<rowTo` or `rowFrom<=rowTo`.

The same goes for your inner loop.